# Information about form sender - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, security, input

I would like to create a group in my app. In model that group has a field `Admin_ID` to specify who is the owner. How to include that information in a form? With hidden field? I don't think this would be safe enough solution... Any other ideas?

Comment: from where the value of "Admin_ID" will comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In model that group has a field Admin_ID to specify who is the owner.

Then apply authentication (see the tutorial for your MVC version) so you know which user is logged in, use authorization to restrict access to admins only and in the controller assign the creating user's ID to the model when it is created:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Create(SomeModel modelToCreate)
{
    // get user, depends on how your project is set up...   
    var user = GetLoggedOnUser();   

    modelToCreate.Admin_ID = user.ID;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If hidden field is not enough for security - don't include it there, but have a separate action that only does operation on your Admin group.

Sorry, can't give more details, as your question does not contain enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You can always save the Admin_ID in the Session.

Answer (score 0):

To better understand:

```
 public class Group
 {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string ID_Admin { get; set; }
 }
```

where `ID_Admin` should be automatically generated when someone who is logged in want to submit that form (he need to fill only A, B and C fields). So let's say currently logged user has ID 42, and he want to submit that form (without any knowledge of that additional field of course) - and I want to include that information about his ID in final model submission.